# EF retrieves incorrect decimal precision

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6.1, code-first. I'm trying to store/retrieve a decimal from SQL Server, but the correct precision isn't retrieved. I read from a .csv file, process the data, then insert into the DB.

- Value in the .csv file: `1.1390`
- Value when saved as `decimal` from the import: `1.1390`
- Value inserted into DB: `1.139`
- Value actually stored/shown in SSMS: `1.1390`
- Value when manually running the query SQL Profiler captures for the retrieval: `1.1390`
- Value retrieved by EF: **`1.1300`**

Everything is working except for retrieving the value. I've tried the solution given in every single other SO post (below), but it has no effect. What's going wrong here? How can I retrieve the correct value with the proper precision?

Supposed solution:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ClassA>().Property(p => p.MyDecimal).HasPrecision(19, 4);
```

Retrieval method, returns type `ClassA` with incorrect precision:

```
_poRepository.Table.FirstOrDefault(p => p.CompNumberA == compNum && 
                                        p.LineNumber == lineNumber);
```

Comparison between the two decimal values:

```
import.MyDecimal != dbValue.MyDecimal
```

`ClassA`:

```
public class ClassA
{
    // properties
    public virtual decimal MyDecimal { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How are you viewing the precision "1.1300"?

Comment: You haven't said what EF approach you are using e.g. Code First and you haven't shown your model. Seems unlikely anyone can help without critical info

Comment: @BradleyUffner My checks for differences in the value returned from the DB and the value given from the .csv file. The comparison shows they're unequal. When I look at the variable at a breakpoint, Visual Studio shows the value as `1.1300`.

Comment: Could you show the code that does the comparison?

Comment: @BradleyUffner Just `import.MyDecimal != dbValue.MyDecimal`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I needed to specify the precision the same way, but in the fluent mapping for `ClassA`. Specifying it in `OnModelCreating()` didn't do it, but in the fluent mapping did. Specifically:

```
Property(u => u.MyDecimal).HasPrecision(19, 4);
```

Answer (score 3):

In Entity Framework Core you can do:

```
[Column(TypeName = "decimal(19,4)")]
public decimal MyDecimal { get; set; }
```